# Display a menu with categories, sub-categories and products - Magento

Tags: magento

I have been looking to implement a menu system like the [following](http://asia-connect.com.vn/2009/07/magento-menu-customization-with-product-list/)

I have 1 category, Cars, with 2 sub-categories, New and Used

I’d like to display, on the drop down, the main category and then New, with all the products inside as a list and then Used, with all the products in a list.

I have tried using the code in the link provided, but it seemed to include a rollover option, that expanded the menu and the products are not listed below the category.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
<?php $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category') ?>
<?php if (count($_categories) > 0): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>">
                    <?php echo $_category->getName() ?>
                </a>
                <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()) ?>
                <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                <?php if (count($_subcategories) > 0): ?>
                    <ul>
                        <?php foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>
                            <li>
                                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>">
                                    <?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Source: http://fishpig.co.uk/magento-tutorials/display-categories-and-subcategories-in-magento